# Async generic retry

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this

```
public static async Task Retry<T>(Func<T> action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int maxAttemptCount = 3)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    for (int attempted = 0; attempted < maxAttemptCount; attempted++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (attempted > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
            }
            return await action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptions.Add(ex);
        }
    }
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

and try to run this by

```
await Retry(() => SaveFile(command, tracker.ActivityId, blobService), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), retryCount);
```

but i got error in Retry in return await action() (T does not contain definition for getAwaiter)

i need to return from the loop when action is done

and my action

```
Task SaveFile<TCommand>(TCommand command, string activityId, IBlobService blobService) where TCommand : DomainComman
```

Comment: If you're expecting to work with async functions, action should be `Func<Task<T>>`, not `Func<T>`. (And, in turn, your return type should be `Task<T>`, not `Task`).

Comment: Also consider `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: Consider using an _exponential retry_ rather than a flat one.   This is useful for busy/offline periods.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so Task<T> Retry<T>(Func<Task<T>> action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int maxAttemptCount = 3) and then await Retry<>(() => SaveFile(command, tracker.ActivityId, blobService), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), retryCount); ? can you post this as an answer ?

Comment: Could you include in the question the signature of the `SaveFile` method?

Comment: OK. I wanted to verify that the `SaveFile` is an asynchronous method. You could have named it `SaveFileAsync` for clarity. The `Retry` could also be named `RetryAsync` for the same reason.

Comment: I recommend using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). It's a battle-tested retry library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1. `action` returns `T`, you cannot await this, you can only await `Task` or `Task<T>`. So if you want to await `action` it should have the signature `Func<Task<T>>`
2. Your return type is wrong. It looks like you want to return a `T`, then the return type should be `Task<T>`
3. If you are using asynchronous code you should not be using `Thread.Sleep`, use `Task.Delay` instead, and await this.

You might also want to add some logging, or a custom exception to make it clearer that this was a repeated failure. Someone looking at a aggregate exception with three duplicates might not immediately figure out what is going on.

Comment: could you also add how to call it now ? i thnk this is correct await Retry<>(() => SaveFile(command, tracker.ActivityId, blobService), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), retryCount);

Comment: @kosnkov the generic type should typically be inferred, If you need to specify it you need to write it out fully `await Retry<SaveFileReturnType>(...)`. An open generic type, i.e. `<>` is very rarely used. This is all assuming SaveFile returns a `Task<T>`, otherwise you need to either move it to a background thread, or call it synchronously.

Comment: my save file looks like this private static async Task SaveFile<TCommand>(TCommand command, string activityId, IBlobService blobService) where TCommand : DomainCommand so what type i should put in Retry<> ? only empty generic Retry<> now compiles

Comment: @Kosnkov So your SaveFile does not return any actual value. If that is the case you should just remove all the `<T>` and the `return` statement. I.e. your method would be equivalent to a `void` method.

Comment: but if I remove return i won't break 'for loop' and endup in throw agregateException isn't ?

Comment: @kosnkov sorry, I'm a bit tired, You should move the return to a separate statement. Since `await action()`  will not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Async functions returns Task for beeing awaitable. So in your code you TResult is T and you need to redifine the `Func<T>` to `Func<Task<T>>`.

As you return the result of action you need also to change the return type of your function to `Task<T>`

So you end up with:

```
public static async Task Retry<T>(Func<T> action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int maxAttemptCount = 3)
```

as SaveFile seams also to be async so you should change the call to:

```
await Retry(async () => await SaveFile(command, tracker.ActivityId, blobService), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), retryCount);
```

Comment: you made two mistakes here in code example, as you mentioned Func<T> must be Func<Task<T>> and then i thnk you need to run it this way await Retry<>(() => SaveFile(command, tracker.ActivityId, blobService), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), retryCount);